# Clio MkII Engine Support

Tags: clutch, renault, clio, motor-mounts

I am planning on replacing the clutch on my '04 16v 1.2L Clio Mk II this week. To do this I'm going to use an engine support beam to very slightly move the engine over to the side.

Where does the engine support beam go on my Clio? It doesn't have the tracks that I've seen most engine support beams slot onto. Do I need to use a makeshift one, and if so where is a nice secure place to rest it under the bonnet?

Picture of under the hood attached.
Thanks,

[image: Under the bonnet of the clio]

Comment: Aftermarket support bars have to be fitted to each engine, you need to look for points on either side of the engine to attach chains or eyelets to the cylinder head or block. Sometimes you have to fabricate eyelets to fit you specific engine.

Answer (score 2):

I did the clutch on one of these Clios and didn't need to support the engine from above at all during the repair.  If I remember rightly, I supported the engine from underneath with a jack and this was more that sufficient to do the repair.

Answer (score 0):

Engine bars are usually supported on the wing rails (with long feet) or, sometimes, on the strut tops - remove the rubber cover - but that does depend on how forward or back the engine / strut tops are.

Comment: Thanks Mike - the wing rails are plastic and won't support the weight of the engine, but the strut tops are certainly sturdy enough. The right lift engine lift point is quite far forward though, to have my engine support beam that far back :L I might use a makeshift beam on a bit of wood bridging from the strut top to the metal rail at the front of the bonnet.

Comment: Gone are the days when a bit of 4*4 across the wings was strong enough...